# Como poner datos de un array con JSONs de python en una tabla de html?

Tags: javascript, html, python, array, json

tengo este codigo:

```
BadJsons.append({"line_number": line_no, "data": JSON})
```

Me devuelve esto: `[{"line_number": 12 , "data": {"id":1, "object_id":None,"value":3}}]`

La parte final de codigo de python es:

```
return JsonResponse({'msg' : f"Se cargaron {len(JSONs)} de {line_no} registros. ", 'badJsons':BadJsons, 'headers':["numero de fila", "Id de objeto","Valor","Id de sensor"]})
```

La cosa es que quiero poner ese JSON en un modal de html en el que `'badJsons'` sea el contenido de una tabla y la cabecera de dicha tabla sea `headers`

Tengo esto en mi codigo de js:

```
var showModal = (message, headers, badJsons) => { //message es el campo 'msg', headers es el campo 'headers' y 'badJsons' es el campo 'badJsons'
    header = headers
    badJson = badJsons
    //faltaria meter las 2 variables al html
    document.getElementById('modal-message').innerHTML = message;
    modal.toggle();
}
```

Y el modal del html es asi:

```
<div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Mensaje</h5>
                        <button id="but-cerrar-2" type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p id="modal-message">Se cargó correctamente la data</p>
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    {% for i in header %}
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            {% header[i] %}
                                        </th>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {% for i in badJson %}
                                    <tr>
                                        {% for j in badJson[i] %}
                                            <td>
                                                {%= badJson[i][j] %}
                                            </td>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>  
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" id="but-cerrar" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

El problema es que cuando ejecuto para que aparezca el modal, me sale error.

PD: Este es el archivo python que recoge los datos:

```
def post(self, request):
        ...
        if str(filename).split('.')[-1] != "csv":
            return HttpResponseServerError(json.dumps({'msg' : 'Archivo no es .csv'}))
        ...
        if filesfiletered:
            return HttpResponseServerError(json.dumps({'msg' : 'Archivo con el mismo nombre ya subido'}))
        ...
        reader = csv.reader(textFile, delimiter=DELIMITER)
        JSONs = []
        BadJsons = []
        for line_no, line in enumerate(reader):
            if (line_no == 0):
                ...
                pass #por ahora esta asi
            else:
                JSON = self.transformLineToJSON(line)
                if(JSON):
                    JSONs.append(JSON)
                else:
                    BadJsons.append({"line_number": line_no, "data": JSON})
        dataStoreConnector = DatastoreConnector()
        #res = dataStoreConnector.write_JSONs(JSONs)
        residuo = line_no - len(JSONs)
        if residuo == 0:
            return JsonResponse({'msg' : f"Se cargaron {len(JSONs)} de {line_no} registros.", 'badJsons': [], 'headers': []})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'msg' : f"Se cargaron {len(JSONs)} de {line_no} registros. ", 'badJsons':BadJsons, 'headers':["numero de fila", "latitud", "longitud", "sensores", "Id de estación", "Id de objeto","timestamp"]})
    
    def transformLineToJSON(self, line):
        json = None
    
        DEFAULT_STATION_ID = 5
        DEFAULT_TEMPERATURE_ID = '32'
        sensorList = {
            "DO": '34',
            "CD": '33',
            "pH": '35',
        }
        object_id = None
        
        COLUMN_TYPE = 1
        COLUMN_DATE = 2
        COLUMN_TIME = 3
        COLUMN_OBJECT = 8
        COLUMN_VALUE = 9
        COLUMN_TEMPERATURE_VALUE = 11
        
        if (line[COLUMN_TYPE] in sensorList):
            firstSensorId = sensorList[line[COLUMN_TYPE]]
        else:
            firstSensorId = None

        DATETIME_SEPARATOR = " "
        DATETIME_TIMEZONE = "-0500"
        date = line[COLUMN_DATE] + DATETIME_SEPARATOR + line[COLUMN_TIME] \
            + DATETIME_TIMEZONE
        if len(date.split("/")) == 3:
            timestamp = datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p%z").timestamp()
        elif len(date.split("-")) == 4:
            timestamp = datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S %p%z").timestamp()

        if (line[COLUMN_OBJECT].split(" ")[0]).isnumeric():
            object_id = int(line[COLUMN_OBJECT].split(" ")[0])
            if not (1 <= object_id <= 13):
                object_id = None
        else:
            object_id = None

        json = { 
            "latitude": 0, 
            "longitude": 0, 
            "sensors": {
                firstSensorId: line[COLUMN_VALUE],
                DEFAULT_TEMPERATURE_ID: line[COLUMN_TEMPERATURE_VALUE]
            }, 
            "station_id": DEFAULT_STATION_ID, 
            "object_id": object_id,
            "timestamp": int(timestamp)
        }
        
        if object_id == None:
            return None
        else:
            return json
```

Comment: ¿En python se permiten  `<%` y  `%>` o estás usando una librería para plantillas? De cualquier forma, me parece que estás mezclando lenguajes.

Comment: me estaba guiando de un proyecto antiguo con node.js y ajax, pero estoy usando django, justo ahora acabo de reemplazar los ````<%```` y ````%>```` por ````{%```` y ````%}```` que son para django, igual sale error

Comment: Es que los datos los recibo del html de un input file, que luego los manda al servidor para transformarlos en jsons y subirlos a la bd del servidor, por eso quiero que esos jsons transformados del codigo del servidor pasen de nuevo al cliente

Comment: Si no estás recibiendo la información por AJAX, entonces debes usar las etiquetas adecuadas de [Django para ciclos](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle)

Comment: es por eso que puse en un comentario arriba que cambie los simbolos por ````{%```` y ````%}```` @Triby

Comment: ya lo hice, igual me salta error

Comment: ya esta editado el post

Comment: ¿Si estás trabajando todo en Python, porqué transformas los datos a JSON, que es una estructura de Javascript?

Comment: Es que los datos del json los tengo que mandar a una base de datos